# Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android, xml, inflate-exception

I have a strange problem,my code work in some device,but on Stock S3 with api 18 (Androdi 4.3) don't work (Caused by: android.view.InflateException)

this is my logcat

```
04-21 00:53:52.150: E/(32638): Device driver API match
04-21 00:53:52.150: E/(32638): Device driver API version: 23
04-21 00:53:52.150: E/(32638): User space API version: 23 
04-21 00:53:52.155: E/(32638): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct  9       21:05:57 KST 2013 
04-21 00:54:00.985: E/dalvikvm-heap(32638): Out of memory on a 3905296-byte allocation.
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to  start activity ComponentInfo{com.keyren.game/game_package_dev.Profile_View}:   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at   android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):   at   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:  Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at  com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java: 56)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at  android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at  android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at  android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):   at  android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):     at  android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):  at   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):   at  android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):   at  game_package_dev.Profile_View.onCreate(Profile_View.java:44)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):    at    android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):     ... 11 more
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638): Caused by:  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):     at  java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):  at  java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):   at  android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):   ... 24 more
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):   at  android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):   at android.view.View.<init> (View.java:3563)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init> (ViewGroup.java:475)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.    <init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
04-21 00:54:01.035: E/AndroidRuntime(32638):  ... 27 more
```

and this is my xml file, can't understand my problem,and why only with s3 don't work i have an S3 too but with custom rom,and work perfectly

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/profileScreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/screen_bk"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_profile"
        style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/profileheader"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/info_prof"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Player_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_profile"
        android:background="@drawable/spaceinfo"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="25dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Name_Field"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:text="@string/Name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Lv_Field"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:text="@string/complete_levels" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Num_Chars_Unlock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:text="@string/Chars_Unlock" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Num_BGs_Unlock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:text="@string/BGs_Unlock" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text_win"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:text="@string/Text_Win" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text_Lose"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:text="@string/Text_Lose" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/field1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Player_info"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Player_info"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/space_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/empty" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textedit_new_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:maxLength="15"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:width="215dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save_button"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
            android:text="@string/save_edit"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/field2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Player_info"
        android:layout_below="@+id/field1"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Player_info"
        android:background="@android:color/black" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/space_lvs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/empty" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/field3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/field2"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Player_info"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chars_unlock_space"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/empty" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/field4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/field3"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Player_info"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bgs_unlock_space"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/empty" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/field5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/field4"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Player_info"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/space_win"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Num_Win" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/field6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/field5"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/field5"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/space_lose"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Num_Lose" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/field7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/space_avatar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/avatar"
            android:src="@drawable/av0" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` sacle down the image `av0`.

Comment: thanks for your reply^^ but how?

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: I have not yet resolved, the stock rom dell's3 causes errors everywhere, linked to the use of memory bitmaps =( Also following the example in the link, do not get results, on devices less performative worked both before and after, on s3 not work in every case

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:largeHeap="true">
```